# Jenkins how to hide system level console output

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to hide all the .bat file wizardry that Jenkins writes out to the build log?

What I get is:

```
[release] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\Jenkins\AppData\...8991397464.bat

c:\Jenkins\jobs\release>python -u my_python.py 
...job output...
c:\Jenkins\jobs\release>exit 0 
Finished: SUCCESS
```

But what I would like to see is simply:

```
...job output...
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I can't find any build verbosity settings in Jenkins anywhere.  It would be nice to be able to turn off the debug info once you have your jobs running stably.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of most, but not all of it by adding `echo off` at the beginning of the execute windows bath command dialog.

Comment: Yes, that does help somewhat, thanks.  Still have the 'cmd /c call...' lines inserted by Jenkins in addition to all the git info provided by the github plugin we are using.

Comment: I'm guessing that the other output is created by each plugin (Git, Batch Command Etc...) individually and could only be turned off by modifying the source for each of those plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simply redirect ('>') the console output to a temporary log file.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you can alter through any of the xml files. Build task commands are called from within the Jenkins build ([Launcher.java](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/Launcher.java)).  An easy way to prevent these commands from displaying in your job's console output is the [Log File Filter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/log-file-filter). I currently use this in my Jenkins instance for this purpose (using Jenkins ver. 2.176.3).  Once installed go to Manage Jenkins > Configure System.  Look for *Log File Filter Global config* , enter .*cmd /c call.* as your *Regexp* and leave the *Replacement* as null.
[image]